# AngularJS select model not updating when filter condition changed

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I've spend hours trying to find a an answer to the following problem.

JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/holbtfuf/o1758k7q/)

Screenshot:

[image]

I have 2 selects:

```
<label>Animal</label>
<select ng-model='myAnimal' ng-options="animal for animal in animals">
  <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
</select>

<label>Action</label>
<select ng-model="myAction" ng-options="action as action.name for action in actions | filter: { usedBy: myAnimal } track by action.id">
  <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
</select>
```

With this javascript:

```
angular.module('CMS', [])
.controller('CMSCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.animals = ["cat", "dog"];
    $scope.actions = [
       {id: 1, name: "walk", usedBy: 'cat,dog'},
       {id: 2, name: "meow", usedBy: 'cat'},
       {id: 3, name: "bark", usedBy: 'dog'}
    ];

  $scope.myAnimal = null;
  $scope.myAction = null;
});
```

The values that are displayed in the 2nd select are filtered depending on what the user selected in the first.

Issue: Select Animal "dog" and Action "bark". Then select Animal "cat". Action is set by AngularJS to "-- Please select --" which is correct (because a cat cannot bark) but the model $scope.action is not updated.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: One approach is to clear out `$scope.myAction` each time an animal is selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution

Here is the updated **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/o1758k7q/6/)**

```js
angular.module('CMS', [])
  .controller('CMSCtrl', function ($scope) {

  $scope.animals = ["cat", "dog"];
  $scope.actions = [
    {id: 1, name: "walk", usedBy: 'cat,dog'},
    {id: 2, name: "meow", usedBy: 'cat'},
    {id: 3, name: "bark", usedBy: 'dog'}
  ];

  $scope.myAnimal = null;
  $scope.myAction = null;
  $scope.callChange = function(){
   if($scope.myAction && $scope.myAction.id != 1){
       $scope.myAction = null;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div ng-app="CMS" ng-controller="CMSCtrl">

  myAnimal {{myAnimal}}
  <br/> myAction {{myAction}}
  <br/>

  <form>

    <label>Animal</label>
    <select ng-model='myAnimal' ng-options="animal for animal in animals" ng-change="callChange()">
      <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
    </select>

    <label>Action</label>
    <select ng-model="myAction" ng-options="action as action.name for action in actions | filter: { usedBy: myAnimal } track by action.id">
      <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
    </select>

  </form>

</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for the fast answer - that works. I was hoping that angularjs would update the model since it already updates the dom. I need to find now a general way to check the filter condition since my real problem is more complex.